VS Code Junit "No test have been found"
I'm using VS Code. I have built a java project and I have therefore some junit tests. I changed from my current project to an older one and then back to the current one and now I am unable to start my junit tests. When I go to the testing area in VS Code, I get the massage "No tests have been found in this workspace yet." The strange thing is, that I have installed all necessary plugins und the tests have worked an houre ago.
Any solutions?

